# Confluent Kafka services (local) do not start properly on wsl2 and seems to timeout communicating their status

Tags: confluent-platform, wsl-2

I am seeing various different issues while trying to start Kafka services on wsl2. Details/symptoms below:

1. Confluent Kafka (7.0.0) platform
2. wsl2 - ubuntu 20.04LTS

When I use the command:

```
confluent local services start
```

Typically the system will take a long time and then exit with service failed (e.g. zookeeper, as that is the first service to start).

If I check the logs, it is actually started. So I again type the command and sure enough it immediately says zookeeper up, then proceed to try start kafka, which again after a min will say failed to start (but it really has started).

I suspect after starting the service (which is quite fast), system is not able to communicate back/exit and thus times out, I am not sure where the logs related to this are.

Can see this in the screenshot below
[image]

This means to start the whole stack (zookeeper/kafka/schema-registry/kafka-rest/kafka-connect/etc), takes forever, and in between I start getting other errors (sometimes, schema-registry is not able to find the cluster id, sometimes its a log file related error), which means I need to destroy and start again.

I have tried this over a couple of days and cant get this to work. Is confluent kafka that unstable on windows or I am missing some config change.

In terms of setup, I have not done any change in the config and am using the default config/ports.

Comment: I'm seeing this same behaviour on bare-metal linux too.

Comment: Hi Peeyush, were you able to solve this problem?